# SSLError no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:4123)

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, ssl, openssl

Отправляю get запрос с помощью requests:

```
import requests


url = "https://somesite/service.php"
response = requests.get(url=url, params=params, verify="consolidate.pem")
    print(response.ok)
    response.close()
```

Ветка сертификатов somesite:

```
Russian Trusted Root CA
    Russian Trusted Sub CA
        *.somesite.ru
```

Сертификаты `Russian Trusted Root CA (root.cer)` и `Russian Trusted Sub CA (trust.cer)` скачал и преобразовал в объединенный `consolidate.pem` через команды:

```
.\openssl x509 -in root.cer -inform DER -outform PEM  >> consolidate.pem
.\openssl x509 -in trust.cer -inform DER -outform PEM  >> consolidate.pem
```

После отправки запроса получаю ошибку:

```
Caused by SSLError(SSLError(136, '[X509: NO_CERTIFICATE_OR_CRL_FOUND] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:4123)')))
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Сертификаты гостовские?

Comment: @PakUula не гостовские.  Алгоритм подписи sha256RSA.